# Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: c#, .net

I have declared one formClosing event procedure on form closing 
here is my code.I'm designing a notepad using c# and before closing the form or my notepad app it should ask user whether he/she wants to save it or not ..

```
private void Form13_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.Text == "Untitled-FileEditor")
        {
            if (richTextBox1.Text.Length > 0)
            {
                DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do u want to save changes to untitled", "FileEditor", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "NewText";
                    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt";
                    DialogResult d = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                    if (d == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        string TextFilePath = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                        richTextBox1.SaveFile(TextFilePath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                        richTextBox1.Text = "";
                    }
                }
                if (dr == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    //richTextBox1.Text = "";
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            else if (richTextBox1.Text.Length == 0)
            { this.Close(); }
        }
        else if (this.Text != "Untitled-FileEditor")
        {
            if (richTextBox1.Modified)
            {
                DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do u want to save changes to " + openFileDialog1.FileName, "FileEditor", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
                if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "NewText";
                    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt";
                    DialogResult d = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
                    if (d == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        string TextFilePath = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
                        richTextBox1.SaveFile(TextFilePath, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                        richTextBox1.Text = "";
                    }
                }
                if (dr == DialogResult.No)
                {
                    //richTextBox1.Text = "";
                    this.Close();
                }
            }
            if (!richTextBox1.Modified)
            {
                this.Text = "Untitled-FileEditor";
                //richTextBox1.Text = "";
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Error showing - An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'richTextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: Check the stack trace.

Comment: You should name your forms and controls.

Comment: Didn't get you .. Can you please elaborate

Comment: @SLaks already I've given names to my controls

Comment: Read the stack trace to see where you're calling something on the wrong thread.

Comment: `richTextBox1` and `Form13` are not useful names.

Comment: sorry I'm in little bit hurry to finish my assignment which i need to submit tomorrow . That's why i named it like that only .. Form13 is my form name

Comment: In this code there is nothing that triggers that exception. When/where is form_closing called? Oh, and we are in a hurry too so don't waste our time...

Comment: Please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the . This is exactly your case.

Comment: just give me a answer of simple question bro .. I want to perform some opertion before form closing .. On which event of form i should write the code ?

Comment: You are pretty rude bro...

Comment: Dude what's wrong with u ? I'm new to .Net world. I'm trying as much as i can .. I've not used any words to hurt u bro .. Everybody is participating and answering my question.. Kindly say if u have any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that you are trying to access/modify data from an other thread than it is allowd to.

Please try:

```
richtextBox1.Invoke(new Action(richtextBox1.Text = "sample text")); //just a sample
```

Instead of `richtextBox1.Text = "sample text"` you write the code of the line where the error appears.

**Maybe you should perform your actions within** `OnClosed` **event:**

```
protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
    base.OnClosed(e);
}
```

Comment: just give me a answer of simple question bro .. I want to perform some opertion before form closing .. On which event of form i should write the code ?

Comment: how can i override OnClosing event sir ?

Comment: tried above method .. still showing that exception.. and the exception raised in designer.cs file .. "base.Dispose(disposing);" -> on this line

Comment: yeah Brother thanx .. this overriden method helped me :) thanx a lot .. I have removed all this.close() functions and it helped me .. thanx a ton .. give this man a cookie

Comment: @chikun No problem,  that what `SO` is here for :D cookie means upvote? :P